# Issue in phrase date format

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

Issue in phrase date format `YYYY-MM-DD`

Common Utility:

```
 public boolean validateDateFormatfortedthb(String datetd,String dateFormat) {
        DateFormat ddf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.UK);
//      DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormatT,Locale.UK);
        try{
            Date valuationDate = ddf.parse(datetd.trim()); // gives you java.util.Date

            return true;
        }catch(ParseException parseEx){
            parseEx.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
}
```

---

calling in function as :

```
@And("^validate the valuation date format for nav is \\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\" in JSON$")
    public void validateDateFieldOfNavFeedw(String dateFormat) throws IOException {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(CommonVariables.outputMessageJson);
        JSONObject headerSec = jsonObject.getJSONObject("domainHeader");
        String datetd = headerSec.getString("valuationDate");
        Assert.assertEquals(true,
                commonUtilities.validateDateFormatfortedthb(datetd, dateFormat));

    }
```

Getting error message as :

```
@Then("^validate the valuation date format for nav is \"([^\"]*)\" in JSON$")
public void validate_the_valuation_date_format_for_nav_is_in_JSON(String arg1) throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

Can anyone please suggest how to fix this?

Comment: Change  \\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"  to  \"(.*)\"

Comment: I reformatted this

Comment: changed the value but still facing the same issue

Comment: did you tried existing `@And("^validate the valuation date format for nav is \\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\" in JSON$")` to one suggested in exception? Try which is suggested in exception. `@Then("^validate the valuation date format for nav is \"([^\"]*)\" in JSON$")` if that is not working it means it's not finding the class where your steps defined. in that case you need to provide proper value for glue.